# C# dialog opened from c++

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, mfc

I have a C++ method which creates a MFC dialog. The method looks like: IDialog* createDialog() - the dialog is derived from IDialog interface; IDialog interface has only one method showDialog().

I am trying to recreate the same dialog but C# wpf. There is any way to add support in C# side for showing the C# wpf dialog, even the createDialog()->showDialog() is called from c++? The c++ side should remain untouched only CLI wrappers are allowed.

Comment: Pretty fuzzy description of what you are trying to achieve. At a guess, you'll need C++/CLI and/or COM.

Comment: May be this can help https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/828736

Comment: as a short summary: I have this call in c++ "createDialog()->showDialog()" which shows the corresponding MFC dialog. What I am trying to do is to replace the MFC dialog with a C# WPF. Note that the dialog is derived from c++ interface IDialog

Comment: You merely repeated, what's in your question already. It wasn't clear the first time around, repeating it did nothing to make this question comprehensible. The issue is likely, that you do not yet understand the problem you need to solve. You'll need to fix that first, and [improve](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39611998/edit) your question when done.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing very hard I think...

1) Create a class and have it implement IDialog interface.
2) Declare the class attribute ComVisible(true)

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

// this works if IDialog is a COM interface
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("your guid goes here")] // don't let the framework generate one that can change from build to build

```
public class MyClass : Window, IDialog
{
   public MyClass()
   {
   }

   public void showDialog()
   {
       // do your magic...
   }       
}
```

Need to use register your DLL:

regasm your.dll /tlb /codebase

You can also just mark the project register for COM interop, but that will only help you on your dev machine.

I assume you know how to instantiate COM objects already...